# Access a form's validity in a service

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-service

In my application I have two forms that are very similar. They each have different controllers and all of the common functionality is stored in one service (VehicleFormService)[image: .]

Each form has subforms. I would like to have common function for both forms that needs to access the validity of the of the subforms. If I was to do it in a controller, I could just do something like this

```
$scope.subForm1.$valid
```

However, since this functionality is common to both, I want to add it in the service but I'm unsure how to access the form validity.

Answer (score 1):

You can synchronize it with a service. Here is a simple service:

```
app.service("formService", function() {
    return {
        isValid: false
    };
});
```

This is the controller that is closest to the form watching it for validity:

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope, formService) {
    var _this = this;
    this.formService = formService;
    this.$scope = $scope;
    $scope.$watch("myForm.$valid", function() {
        _this.formService.isValid = _this.$scope.myForm.$valid;
    });
});
```

And this controller watches the service to update the validity in its own $scope (it gets called during digest loops and refreshes the value from the service):

```
app.controller("secondController", function($scope, formService) {
    var _this = this;
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.formService = formService;
    $scope.isValid = formService.isValid;
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return _this.formService.isValid;
    }, function() {
        _this.$scope.isValid = _this.formService.isValid;
    });
});
```

The fully functional fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/Gz77C/

Comment: Also, just noting you were asking how to "access the form validity." Give the form a name (name="xyz") then you access it via $scope.xyz.$valid ... the form is automatically added to the $scope for the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property to the service and then in the controller

```
angular.extend($scope,myservice)
$scope.$watch('subForm1',furnction(){});
```

or an other approach set up a parentCtrl doing so you can exploit it
in the children controller